# div moving down while defining a new div or span inside it

Tags: html, sass

having issue with crating a simple project, two divs near each other, when adding a span or div inside one it collapses (moves) down, don't have a clue what may be causing it!

```
   <article id="categorical__offers__2st__container">
        <div id="categorical__offers__2st__container__right">
          <div id="categorical__offers__2st__container__right__top">
            <span>hi</span>         <!-- adding this causes problem -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="categorical__offers__2st__container__left">

        </div>
   </article>
```

**SCSS:**

```
 #categorical__offers__2st__container{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    max-width: 1330px;
    min-width: 1000px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 405px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    img{
      width: 100%;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    #categorical__offers__2st__container__right{
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: white;
      width: 81%;
      margin-left: 2.5%;
      height: 405px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      #categorical__offers__2st__container__right__top{
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        span{
          height: 50px;
          width: 170px;
          border-bottom: 1px solid red;
        }
      }
    }
    #categorical__offers__2st__container__left{
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: white;
      width: 16%;
      height: 405px;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
  }
```

**when adding a div or span inside:**

[image: when adding a div or span inside:]

**without a div or span inside:**

[image: without a div or span inside:]

Answer (score 0):

was able to get rid of the issue by giving flout right and left for each div out side!
but still want to fix the issue without using float